# How to get elements matching a partial text

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using NEST to create services, so I can search into a field (label)

Is there a way to get answers from a partial string ?

For example, if I have three labels : "John Doe" , "Dadido" and "Unicorn", if I type "Do", I get the two first ones

For now, I have this :

```
elasticClient.Search<ESbase>(s => s.Query(q=>q.Regexp(c => 
                                              c.Name("label_query")                                                                                                                                     
                                              .Field(p =>p.Label).Value('*'+label+'*'))));
```

And when I try it, it doesn't send anything back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`match: { text: '.*label.*'}`should work

If you want use regex: `Value(".*label.*")`

I assume you used default maping and in your label string you dont have special character.

Edit: use wildcard work too `.Wildcard("*label*")`

Comment: I tried with the `s=> s.Query(q=> q.Match(m => m.Text  `but it didn't propose anything :/
I've tried with the correct regex, and it works, thanks :)

Comment: I should have ask your mapping first you can also use wildcard:{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "fieldname" : "*label*" }
    }
}